# Do we know Bakugou's actual hero name?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I couldn't find any notions of his final choice in the manga, and I think he does not mention it anywhere. Is there any reliable source for his hero name, or it has not been decided / revealed yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiroshiki's first draft has a name, that roughly translates to Ground Zero.

[image: Bakugou First Draft Codename]

But in my opinion, Kachhan is not too bad either.